# Faster computation to get multiples of number at different levels

Tags: algorithm, excel, vba

Here is the scenario:

We have several items that are shipped to many stores.  We want to be able to allocate a certain quantity of each item to a store based on need.  Each of these stores is also associated to a specific warehouse.

The catch is that at the **warehouse** level, the total quantity of each item must be a multiple of a number (6 for example).

I have already calculated out the quantity needed by each store at **store** level, but they do not sum up to a multiple of 6 at the **warehouse** level.

My solution was this using Excel:

Using a SUMIFS formula to keep track of the sum of each item allocated at the **warehouse** level.  Then another MOD(6) formula that calculates the remaining until a multiple of 6.  Then my actually VBA code loops through and subtracts 1 (if MOD <= 3) or adds (if MOD > 3) from the **store** level units needed until MOD = 0 for all rows.

Now this works for me, but is extremely slow even when I have just ~5000 rows.

I am looking for a faster solution, because everytime I subtract/add to units needed, the SUMIFS and MOD need to be calculated again.

**EDIT: (trying to be clearer)**

I have a template file that I paste my data into with the following setup:

```
+------+-------+-----------+----------+--------------+--------+
| Item | Store | Warehouse | StoreQty | WarehouseQty | Mod(6) |
+------+-------+-----------+----------+--------------+--------+
|    1 |     1 |         1 |        2 |            8 |      2 |
|    1 |     2 |         1 |        3 |            8 |      2 |
|    1 |     3 |         1 |        1 |            8 |      2 |
|    1 |     4 |         1 |        2 |            8 |      2 |
|    2 |     1 |         2 |        1 |            4 |      2 |
|    2 |     2 |         2 |        3 |            4 |      2 |
+------+-------+-----------+----------+--------------+--------+
```

Currently the WarehouseQty column is the SUMIFS formula summing up the StoreQty for each Item-Store combo that is associated to the Warehouse.  So I guess the Warehouse/WarehouseQty columns is actually duplicated several times every time an Item-Store combo shows up.  The WarehouseQty is the one that needs to be a multiple of 6.

Comment: Im going to try that now.  Although I am also updating the Application.Status to tell what row I am on, would that affect speed significantly as well?

Answer (score 0):

Screen updating can be turned OFF to speed up length computations like this:

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = FALSE
```

The opposite assignment turns screen updating back on again.

Comment: I'm running it with the ScreenUpdating = FALSE and the performance doesn't seem to be too much better.  I'm also updating the status bar telling me what row its calculating on, would removing this sattus update improve performance much?

Comment: It shouldn't unless you are refeshing the ProgresBar setting much more frequently than once per loop iteraion.

Answer (score 0):

Guessing you may find that stopping the screen refresh may help quite a chunk and therefore not need any more suggestions.

Another option would be to reduce your adjustment to a quantity which is divisible by 6 to a number of if statements, depending on the value of `mod(6)`.

You could also address how you sum up the number of a particular item across all stores, using a pivot table and reading the sum totals from there is a lot quicker than using `sumifs` in a macro

Based on your modifications to the question:

You're correct that you could have huge amounts of replication doing the calculation row by row, as well as adjusting the quantity by a single unit at a time even though you know exactly how many units you need to add / remove from the mod(6) formula.

Could you not create a new sheet with all your possible combinations of product Id and store.  You could then use sumifs() for each of these unique combinations and in a final step round up/down at a warehouse level?

Comment: Using a pivot table, I think I'd need to refresh the table everytime I subtracted/added quantity, would that be equally as slow than re-calculating the sumif?

Comment: OK sorry I didn't spot you were adjusting at the store level.  Looks like you've got some other good suggestions worth looking into.  Would you need to refresh the the pivot table - are you not then checking that a number you know is divisible by 6 really is?  I may well not have picked up the crux of your specific question...

Comment: Edited my post with the actual table, hopefully it makes it clearer.

Answer (score 0):

put the data into an array first, rather than cells, then put the data back after you have manipulated it - this will be much faster.

an example which uses your criteria:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()
Dim q() 'this is what will be used for the range
Dim i As Long

q = Range("C2:C41") 'put the data into the array - *ALWAYS* 2 dimensions, even if a single column
For i = LBound(q) To UBound(q) ' use this, in case it's a dynamic array - 1 to 40 would have worked here
    Select Case q(i, 1) Mod 6 ' calculate remander
        Case 0 To 3
            q(i, 1) = q(i, 1) - (q(i, 1) Mod 6) 'make a multiple of 6
        Case 4 To 5
            q(i, 1) = q(i, 1) - (q(i, 1) Mod 6) + 6 ' and go higher in the later numbers
    End Select
Next i

Range("D2:D41") = q ' drop the data back

End Sub
```

Comment: I'm trying to round to a multiple at warehouse level (thus my need for the SUMIFS formula), but the number I'm actually changing is at the store level (multiple stores map to one warehouse), so I don't think this would make thing run any faster..